# DataAvailable is false but more data should have been sent

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

I have these two methods:

```
public QueryResult ListenForConnection()
    {
        if (!ServerStarted)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            Listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 4044);
            Listener.Start();
            ServerStarted = true;                
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                TcpClient tcpClient = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                byte[] requestByteBuffer = new byte[1024];
                NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                stream.Read(requestByteBuffer, 0, requestByteBuffer.Length);
                string httpMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(requestByteBuffer, 0, requestByteBuffer.Length);
                Query query = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Query>(httpMessage);
                QueryResult queryResult = QueryService.ExecuteQuery(query);
                string queryResultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryResult);
                byte[] responseByteBuffer = new byte[1024];
                responseByteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(queryResultJson);
                stream.Write(responseByteBuffer, 0, responseByteBuffer.Length);
                stream.Flush();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new QueryResult("Failed", null, null);
        }


    }
```

and

```
public QueryResult ProcessRemoteQuery(Query query)
    {
        Byte[] byteBuffer = new Byte[1024];
        string jsonSerializedQuery = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
        byteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonSerializedQuery);
        NetworkStream stream = Client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        Byte[] responseByteBuffer = new Byte[1024];
        int responseBytes = stream.Read(responseByteBuffer, 0, responseByteBuffer.Length);
        string jsonDeserializedQueryResult = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseByteBuffer, 0, responseBytes);
        QueryResult response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueryResult>(jsonDeserializedQueryResult);
        return response;
    }
```

For some reason, DataAvailable is false in ProcessRemoteQuery, meaning stream.Read() never returns and blocks my application. The weird thing is, this only happens the second time, so I the first ProcessRemoteQuery works fine, but the second never does. Is there a bug with the code here? I've not included the code that actually initialises the client, but I assure you it is done. It seems like ListenForConnection should definitely return data each time? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You still have a bug in `ListenForConnection` - no socket code should ever be ignoring the return value from `Read`. You may have only received as little as one byte. There's no 1-1 association between `Write`s on one side and `Read`s on the other side. If you want *messaging*, it's up to *you* to implement that (i.e. fixed size messages, some kind of framing, etc) or move up to a higher level abstraction than TCP, which is just "a stream of bytes".

Answer (score 0):

So I was very very silly, and had recently changed this so that the client doesn't connect each time. Listener.AcceptTcpClient was waiting for a new client after the first message was sent, and was never getting one, blocking the whole thing.

Comment: Yes I have, I have since refactored the connection logic a fair bit anyway.